Issues with Customizing Row Heights and Centering in LaTeX Tables
I need to create a table with custom row heights, but I'm encountering some issues. Specifically, I need to set the first row to a height of 1.5x the normal line height and the rest of the rows to 2x, while ensuring that the content in each column remains properly centered both horizontally and vertically.
Here's the code I'm using:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|M{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Student} & \textbf{Course} & \textbf{Contribution} & \textbf{Picture} \\ \hline
    Billy Surname & Mechanical Engineering & Results, Theory, Recommendations & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\ \hline
    Andrew Surname & Aviation & Introduction & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\ \hline
    Lucas Surname & Astro & Results & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\ \hline
    James Surname & Mechanical Engineering & Discussion, References & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\ \hline
    Judas Surname & Civil Engineering & No Contribution & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


I've tried using \rule{0pt}{value} and \\[valuept] to adjust the row heights, but these methods disrupt the centering of the content, particularly the first and last columns.
I'm looking for a way to adjust the row height without affecting the alignment of the content, especially in the first and last columns. Has anyone else faced this issue or found a solution that works well for row height customization without messing with content centering?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Have a look at the tabularray package, it makes it easy to change heights and alignments.

@Mensch are you’re suggesting that I should make my LaTeX code into a Minimal Working Example (MWE) that can be compiled. I updated my post to include a  compilable snippet. i could be missunderstanding what you mean if so sorry

The tabularray package makes it easy to adjust the height of all or just specific rows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Q[4cm]Q[4cm]Q[4cm]Q[3cm]},
  hlines,vlines,
  cells={valign=m,halign=c},
  rows={ht=2\baselineskip},
  row{1}={ht=1.5\baselineskip,font=\bfseries},
}
    Student & Course & Contribution & Picture \\ 
    Billy Surname & Mechanical Engineering & Results, Theory, Recommendations & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\ 
    Andrew Surname & Aviation & Introduction & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\ 
    Lucas Surname & Astro & Results & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\ 
    James Surname & Mechanical Engineering & Discussion, References & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\ 
    Judas Surname & Civil Engineering & No Contribution & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Thank you so much! I was just looking into tabular arrays from your comment, but you saved me a lot of time. Much appreciated!

@Sak You're welcome!
